# Use the SQLAlchemy session in custom Flask-SQLAlchemy query method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to create a custom method to tell me whether a row exists in my database. The SQLAlchemy `exists` method returns a subquery but doesn't execute anything, so I wanted to create the method `does_exist`, which will simply return `True` or `False`. Here is my code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, BaseQuery, Model

class CustomBaseQuery(BaseQuery):
    def does_exist(self):
        return db.session.query(self.exists()).scalar()

db = SQLAlchemy(app, query_class=CustomBaseQuery)
```

This actually does work, but it seems wrong to refer to `db.session` within the body of the method, which thus depends on later naming the SQLAlchemy instance `db`. I would like to find a way to reference the eventual `db.session` object in a more general way.

Full working example here: https://gist.github.com/wbruntra/3db7b630e6ffb86fe792e4ed5a7a9578

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though undocumented, the session used by the `Query` object is accessible as

```
self.session
```

so your more generic `CustomBaseQuery` could look like

```
class CustomBaseQuery(BaseQuery):
    def does_exist(self):
        return self.session.query(self.exists()).scalar()
```